# Adding two same rows in array than modifying only one of them

Tags: javascript

First, I am adding two same rows in array and later I need to modify only the last one, adding new property to it. The way I do that:

```
for(var index in arrayOne) {
   var arrayOneItem = arrayOne[index];
   var new_row = {
      address: arrayOne[index].address,
      date: arrayOne[index].date,
      category: arrayOne[index].category,
   };
   rows.push(new_row);
   if(arrayOne[index].refund_status == 'refunded') {
      rows.push(new_row);
      rows[rows.length - 1].refund_status = 'refunded'; 
   }
}
```

But the problem is that the code inside `if` statement does not only modify last row, but also the one before it, so the `refund_status = 'refunded'` is added both to the last and one before last row. Why is this happening and is there a way to modify the last row only?

Comment: **Aside note:** Avoid the use of operator `in` to iterate, sometimes the array which is an object, could contain additional properties which are not indexes.  Instead, embrace the operator `for...of` statement.

Comment: @Ele Got it, what should I use instead?

Comment: Please provide your arrayOne value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the same object twice it's best to create a copy (shallow in this case) using Object.assign(). This will avoid referencing the same object from multiple variables or array indexes in your case.

eg. 
`rows.push(new_row);`

becomes

`rows.push(Object.assign({}, new_row));`

Comment: Other solutions also work, but this one was the fastest, and also not complicated

Answer (score 1):

This is because the object you push into the array is passed by reference and not by value, thus when you change the original object you will change both references to it in the array, see example below:

```js
let someArray = [];
let someObj = {foo: "bar"};
someArray.push(someObj);
someArray.push(someObj);
someArray[0].foo = "baz";
console.log(someArray[1]);
```

To avoid this, you would need to clone the values of the object to create a new one. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) question has some ways to do so, using `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` is the shortest way to deep-copy an object without an external library, see example below:

```js
let someArray = [];
let someObj = {foo: "bar"};
someArray.push(someObj);
let newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(someObj));
someArray.push(newObj);
someArray[0].foo = "baz";
console.log(someArray[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are changing property of an `object`, and `object` in javaScript is accessed through a link not a separate instance. In another words, you have the same object in memory and you change its property. It means, `new_row` is object you create and push it several times, and it's the same.
 You can avoid it by copying it when pushing second times:

```
if(arrayOne[index].refund_status == 'refunded') {
      rows.push({ ...new_row });
      rows[rows.length - 1].refund_status = 'refunded'; 
   }
```

where `{ ...new_row }` basically creates new copy.
When you do `rows[rows.length - 1].refund_status = 'refunded';` only second last will change.

Another solution i'd suggest is a bit more accurate:

```
const rows = []; // empty
const arrayOne = []; // SOME DATA HERE as I understand
const refundedStatus = ;

arrayOne.forEach(element=> {
    rows.push(element);

    if (value.refund_status === 'refunded') {
        rows[rows.length].refund_status = 'refunded'; 
        rows.push({ ...element});

    }
});
```